# Where can I get authentic Yab-Yum statues/figurines?

Tags: tantra, statue

Ebay and Amazon have either very large and (prohibitively) expensive ones or those mass-produced in China. Where can I get a bronze or brass figurine that is small in size. Thank you.

Comment: If this question should or shouldn't be reopened, please post your opinion or vote on it here on meta: **[Are "Where can I buy X" questions allowed?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2215/254)**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "shopping" questions are discouraged, and usually considered off-topic, on all StackExchange sites.

Comment: @ChrisW Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post on the meta site. Where can I go to get some guidance on this requirement?

Comment: There's some further guidance at [Why are “shopping list” questions bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/139866).

Comment: I just upvoted this question in order to give you a reputation of "5", which should mean that you can now post on meta if you want to.

Comment: Why do you lust after worldly goods so?

Comment: @majenko - It's not for me. A senior practitioner wants one to replace the one they lost. And asked if I can help find one. I feel it is my duty to try sincerely since I owe them for their time and wisdom and guidance.

Comment: @ChrisW  Do I have to register to post on meta? This is the comment I want to post on meta "But what is the article being sought is one that helps in one's sadhana/practice? Such questions may be allowed?"

Comment: Apparently yes, you would have to register, according to this post: [Why can't unregistered users post on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81972/139866) I'm sorry you want one and haven't been able to find one (yet) but I wouldn't have an answer to that comment/question if you did post it on meta. It may be that no-one would have an answer (to this closed question) even if you were allowed to ask it here. Also fwiw I don't know what "authentic" means, i.e. how do you judge whether something is authentic or not.